# Web front-end to administering users/groups with smbldap

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ldap

I'm using smbldap tools on an Ubuntu Hardy infrastructure, and I'd like to be able to provide a web front-end for non-technical users to manipulate users and group membership.  Does such a beast exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're not going to find many tools in the Open Source world for "less technical" users managing smbldap/openldap directories short of writing one yourself. Our consulting business used/recommended:

- phpldapadmin
- jxplorer

Both of which are "ldap-y" in that they use DNs etc. If you don't want userid management folks to see that or have to deal with it, then you'll probably need to write your own tool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://lam.sourceforge.net/

I did a quick Google search this looked promising.

Might be of some help.

Comment: Given this is for non-technical users, I don't think an interface which exposes DN suffixes and the like is really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked into webmin? Webmin has to my knowledge modules for samba and for ldap. Maybe it does what you need to do. http://www.webmin.com/